# R Remove multiple seasonality in one time series

Tags: r, time-series

I'm dealing with hourly data and my data has 24 hours & 168 hours seasonality.

When I use that code. I removed 24 hours seasonality.

```
deseasonalized_ec_hourly<-electricity_consumption_ts_hourly/ec_hourly_multip$seasonal
```

But 168 hours seasonality remains. How can I remove 168 hours seasonality

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using half-hourly electricity consumption from England and Wals (June - August 2000). The seasonality (daily and weekly) is estimated using the `mstl()` function from the `forecast` package. The `seasadj()` function removes the seasonal components.

```r
library(forecast)

autoplot(taylor)
```

[image]

```r
adjust <- taylor %>% mstl() %>% seasadj()
autoplot(adjust)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>